# Bug in AsyncTask causing random response

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask for a network call. If successful, it should return a JSON Array, and so far it works well on the device I test(Google nexus 5).
But on a Motorola device, it does not work. In the sense, it is not even sending a request to the server.

Here is the code :

```
private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Engine");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)   {
        String result = "";
        try {

            //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number",details));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        //Log.w("PREMIERE::::",result);
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)  {
        //dialog.dismiss();
        try {
            if ((this.dialog != null) && this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Handle or log or ignore
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // Handle or log or ignore
        } finally {
            this.dialog = null;
        }
        showData(jsonString);
    }
}

private void showData(String jsonString)
{
   // try
   // {
        Log.w("VALS:",""+jsonString);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
        {
            MainPojo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MainPojo.class);
            uid.add(cse);

        }
        if(!uid.isEmpty())
        {
            new SimpleTask2().execute(URL2);
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Invalid Credentials", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   /*
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Check data connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

}
```

And I purposefully, did not catch exception, and traced the bug via Crashlytics. The bug occurs on this line.

```
JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
```

which says :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON
>   Array.

Which I believes also occurs when the response is empty, and since I can't also trace a request in server, I believe this is because No request is being sent.(Correct me if wrong).

So, **my question is** : Am I missing something | or is there anything wrong in the way I defined AsyncTask?

**EDIT 1**

> PS: I am using an HTTPS URL in this AsyncTask

Comment: In your `doInBackground` you are ignoring some of exceptions. Try to log them.

Comment: What does this Log statement write to the log? `Log.w("VALS:",""+jsonString);`

Comment: @StephenC , On my device I get the correct string, but on the other device, I dont have logcat connected, only got Crashlytics. Which only gets crash traces !

Comment: Well you need to solve THAT problem first.  'Cos otherwise you can only guess at the problem.

Comment: There is something wrong with your response. It might be possible that your web service might be returning jsonObject and you are trying to get JsonArray. Confirm this thing first

Comment: Another possibility is that it is not JSON ... but an HTML document with an error message; e.g. 'cos the URL is wrong, and you are talking to the wrong server.

Answer (score 1):

In Crashalitics you can log debug messages and stack traces from exceptions that were caught. So the answer for you is to proper collect this information, and then the issue will be clear

```
   // catch everythin n log everything
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       Crashlytics.logException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
```

also put log messages before the possible crash

```
Crashlytics.log("Here is the async task that keeps giving me headache");
```